Problema para ejecutar la libreria Tkinter en un ambiente virtual Poetry
que tal.
En esta ocasión les planteo un problema al cual me estoy enfrentando y que me parece curioso y extraño al mismo tiempo ya que estoy desarrollando una interfaz gráfica con la librería customtkinter (la cual por cierto es fantástica en su presentación visual y que recomiendo ampliamente puedan conocer, probar y usar) en un ambiente virtual Poetry en donde estoy usando python 3.10 para hacer este desarrollo.
El problema que estoy observando es que al momento de ejecutar la aplicación (poetry run python aplicacion.py) me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:
❯ poetry run python3 gui_prueba.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/Documentos/Python/Proyectos/Domotica/GUI/tests/complex_example.py", line 1, in 
import tkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
De entrada es muy raro ya que todos sabemos que tkinter esta incorporado a Python, estoy ejecutando Poetry desde un ambiente Linux 22.04. El error me resulta muy raro ya que en teoría esto no debería suceder, dadas estas circunstancias acudo a la comunidad para saber si alguien se ha topado con una experiencia similar y pueda compartirnos quizás alguna solución.
Desde ya infinitas gracias y saludos a la comunidad.

¿Es tu caso?

SOLUCION ENCONTRADA: faltaba instalar en sistema paquetes, no es un problema de Poetry ni de Python ni del Sistema. Con el comando sudo apt-get install python3-tk queda este problemita solucionado. :D

Ponlo entonces como respuesta, y acéptala cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Gracias @padaleiana :)

SOLUCION ENCONTRADA: faltaba instalar en sistema un paquete, no es un problema de Poetry ni de Python ni del Sistema. Con el comando sudo apt-get install python3-tk queda este problemita solucionado. :D

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.

Un par de aclaraciones, que puedes agregar a la respuesta si lo consideras oportuno: en la gran mayoría de distros de linux es común que los módulos de tkinter se distribuyan en un paquete distinto al intérprete python, por lo que si se usa el intérprete provisto por el sistema (por el gestor de paquetes del mismo), generalmente tendremos que instalar el paquete "python-tkinter" (además de "tcl-tk").

El nombre del paquete y lógicamente el gestor de paquetes varía dependiendo de la distribución,  apt-get install python3-tk es para distribuciones basadas en debian, incluida ubuntu, en fedora  sería dnf install python3-tkinter,  en openSuse zypper in  python-tk, en Arch  pacman -S tk, etc
